# Is there anyway to batch create 30+ logos but change text on each one?

Tags: image-processing, batch-processing, photoshop

I need to create 30+ logos in a similar style to this:
http://www.manchestertaxicomparison.co.uk/wp-content/themes/ilfordtaxis/images/logo.png

Only thing that changes will be the top text, i.e Manchester -> Newcastle

I have to do this many time and as such would love to know if there is anyway to automate it.

Kind regards,
Jack

Comment: Have you googled for "photoshop automation"? Any specific programming language you're going to code in with? Because otherwise this is off topic, and better asked on Superuser

Comment: Photoshop automation produces some interesting results. I'll look into them and post a solution if I find one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would do it with **ImageMagick** at the command line like this:

```
convert -pointsize 72 -background none -fill "rgb(254,203,54)" \
  label:"LEEDS" -resize 170x30! base.png +swap                 \
  -geometry +40+0 -composite result.png
```

[image]

And then do all 30 of them in a simple loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for city in LEEDS LIVERPOOL EDINBURGH CARDIFF; do
   convert -pointsize 72 -background none -fill "rgb(254,203,54)" label:"$city" -resize 170x30! base.png +swap -geometry +40+0 -composite "$city.png"
done
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that there are other words not necessarily visible on StackOveflow's white background.
[image]

**ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.